# SQL Bitwise in SmallInt

Tags: sql-server

I've got a question about storing bitwise flags in sql. I have a number of status flags which i'd like to store in a SQL smallint field. So a smallint can represent -32768 to 32767.

If I want to use all 32 bits to store boolean values how do I reference the bits. For instance. If I want to store bits that make up the number 1 i would normally see 31 zeros and a 1 in the LSB. Would would that sequence equate to as a value in my smallint field? What about 1 in the MSB and zero in all other bits? Maybe there is a better way to store and query bitwise data in SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) datatype? One per flag you need

SQL Server packs bit columns into as many bytes as needed

- upto 8 = 1 byte
- 9-16 is 2 bytes
- ...

The DB engine will also take care of all bit masks etc for you
All you see are discrete bit values

So... why roll your own?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want 32 columns in his table, or accesses the value externally in a piece of code.

Comment: I would've accepted @muhmud answer but he deleted it. I have 96 columns representing 15 minute intervals in a day so his answer was the cleanest in my circumstance.

Comment: I didn't delete it! For some reason someone called Will did. Here is the SQL if you need it: "select cast(16 as varbinary(4)), cast(cast(16 as varbinary(4)) & cast(0x0000010 as int) as varbinary(4))"

Answer (score -2):

The ideal solution would be to use 32 separate TinyInt fields.  TinyInt supports values 0-255.  If you try to use a single field and do bit processing you lose the ability to index any of these flags just as you would if you used Bit type fields.

Comment: So you propose using 32 bytes vs 4 bytes using bit? bit can also be indexed using raw SQL: only the SSMS GUI disallows it. Finally, if the tinyint only contains 0 or 1, then it isn't a good candidate for an index anyway, just like bit.

Comment: @Data Masseur - With bitwise operations, you can do an index on a computed column that is the result of applying a mask.